Ionic 5 Android 13+ pick file from google drive using <input type='file' /> throwing error
Ionic 5 Android 13+ pick file from google drive using
<input type='file' /> 
Throwing error DOMException: The requested file could not be read, typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference to a file was acquired
Html code -
<input  type="file"
        accept="*" 
        hidden="true" 
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.target['value']=null;" 
        (change)="pickFile($event)"> />

Typescript code -
pickFile(ev) {
     let file = event && event.target.files[0];
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = (_event: any) => {
     }
     reader.onerror = (_event: any) => { 
     // error -
       DOMException: The requested file could not be read, 
       typically due to permission problems that have occurred after a reference 
       to a file was acquired.
     }
}


What <uses-permission> entries are in your AndroidManifest.xml file?
